# Pass a variable from postDispatch() to view instance in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a controller plugin with `postDispatch()` hook, and there I have a `$variable`.

How to pass this variable to the `view` instance?

I tried `Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView()`, but this returns new view instance (not the application resource). The same with `$bootstrap->getResource('view')`.

I don't want to pass it as a request param.
Now, as a workaround I do it using `Zend_Registry`.

But, is it the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using the ViewRenderer action helper to get the view when I need it.  It seems to be the most common way that Zend classes access the view object.

**So, in the controller plugin:**

```
class App_Controller_Plugin_ViewSetup extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {

  public function postDispatch() {

    $view = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer')->view;

    echo $view->variable;

    $view->variable = 'Hello, World';

  }

}
```

**In the controller:**

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

  public function indexAction() {

    $this->view->variable = 'Go away, World';

  }

}
```

**In the view script:**

```
<?php echo $this->variable; ?>
```

**The output is:** Go away, WorldGo away, World

It seems like the problem is that the view script renders before the postDispatch() method is called, because this *does* return the main view object.

Answer (score 3):

**in the plugin:**

```
class App_Plugin_MyPlugin extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract{


public function preDispatch (Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request){
    $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer');
    $viewRenderer->setNeverRender(true);
}

public function postDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request){
   $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer');
   $view = $viewRenderer->view;
   $view->variable = 'new value';
   $viewRenderer->render();

}

}
```

**In the controller:**

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

```
  public function indexAction() {

    $this->view->variable = 'value';

  }
```

}

**In the view script:**

```
<?php echo $this->variable; ?>
```

The output is: new value

Answer (score 0):

```
class ZFExt_Controller_Plugin_Passvar extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract 
{
    public function postDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {

        $view = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()
                      ->getParam('bootstrap')
                      ->getResource('view');
        $view->variable = 'Hi there';
    }
}
```

Then in the view script

```
<p><?php echo $this->variable; ?></p>
```